# Haskell - generate missing argument error message from either data type

Tags: haskell, testing, optionparser

I have the following piece of code;

```
module Billing.Options
  (
      GlobalOpts(..)
    , globalOptsParser
    , parseDb
    , parseSql
  ) where

import Options.Applicative
import Options.Applicative.Simple
import Options.Applicative.Types
import System.FilePath.Posix
import Text.Regex.PCRE

-- ------------------------------------------------------------

data GlobalOpts = GlobalOpts
  {
    optDb          :: String,
    optSql         :: String
  } deriving Show

-- ------------------------------------------------------------

globalOptsParser :: Parser GlobalOpts
globalOptsParser = GlobalOpts
  <$> option (parseDb =<< readerAsk)
    (   long "db"
    <>  short 'd'
    <>  metavar "<DB name>"
    <>  help "dmt | report"
    )
  <*> option parseSql
    (   long "sql"
    <>  metavar "<SQL SELECT statement>"
    <>  help "sql select statement to use in order to generate JSON config file"
    )
-- ------------------------------------------------------------

matches :: String -> String -> Bool
matches = (=~)

-- ------------------------------------------------------------

parseDb :: String -> ReadM String
parseDb val = do
    if not (elem val ["dmt", "report"])
        then readerError $ "Unknown DB, '" ++ val ++ "'"
        else return val

-- ------------------------------------------------------------

parseSql :: ReadM String
parseSql = do
    val <- readerAsk
    if not (val `matches` "(?i)select .+ from .+")
        then readerError $ "Please provide a valid SQL SELECT statement"
        else return val

-- [EOF]
```

I'm testing my argument parser with the following code;

```
error' = let mp = runParser AllowOpts globalOptsParser ["-d", "billing"]
          opts = ParserPrefs "suffix" False False False 80
      in fst $ runP mp opts
```

The required arguments are,

```
  -d <DB name>
  --sql <SQL SELECT statement>
```

I want to test that I get the error message,

```
Missing: --sql <SQL SELECT statement>
```

when I only specify "-d billing".

The above test code gives the following output if I print the result,

```
Left (MissingError (MultNode [MultNode [MultNode [AltNode [Leaf (Chunk {unChunk = Just --sql <SQL SELECT statement>})]]]]))
```

Is there a way to generate the expected error message (String) from the above result (Either data type)?  Does Haskell provide an obvious function to use for this purpose as I cannot find something in the documentation and googling for examples also didn't produce any answers.

Comment: There are a gazillion command-line option libraries for Haskell, so you really should tell us what library you are using and include your imports.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my question.

Comment: @TresiaBurger  So....  are you using `http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative` then?

Comment: Yes that is the one I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code repository for `optparse-applicative` [(link)](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative) you'll see that it itself has a test suite in the `tests` subdirectory.

A routine which looks like it does a lot like what you want is [`checkHelpTextWith`](https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/blob/cac69ccf98f3ed2f9d2f30ec97daa226082920a5/tests/Tests.hs#L66) in the file `tests/Test.hs`:

```
checkHelpTextWith :: Show a => ExitCode -> ParserPrefs -> String
                  -> ParserInfo a -> [String] -> Assertion
checkHelpTextWith ecode pprefs name p args = do
  let result = execParserPure pprefs p args
  assertError result $ \failure -> do
    expected <- readFile $ name ++ ".err.txt"
    let (msg, code) = renderFailure failure name
    expected @=? msg ++ "\n"
    ecode @=? code
```

This function expects an option parser to fail and compares the error message with the contents of a file.

The main functions of interest are:

```
execParserPure :: ParserPrefs -> ParserInfo a -> [String] -> ParserResult a

renderFailure :: ParserFailure ParserHelp -> String -> (String, ExitCode)
```

The String returned by `renderFailure` is the error message.